# Electron notification API 'click' event not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a problem where the [experimental electron notification API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/notification) doesn't submit the 'click' event or I am simply using it wrong however I want to be clear this is the new notification system that runs in the main process not in the renderer process:

My Code:

```
notification = new Notification({title: "Message Received",body: "message body"}).show()
// The above works and a notification gets made

notification.on('click', (event, arg)=>{
  console.log("clicked")
})

// The above gives an error about 'on' not being defined
```

Things tried:

```
notification.once('click', (event, arg)=>{
  console.log("clicked")
})
```

```
notification.onclick = () =>{
  console.log("clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a small flaw in your code: right now, the variable `notification` does not receive the result of the call to `new Notification()`, but instead the result of the call to `show()` which is `undefined` (returns nothing).

This is fairly easy to fix by splitting the line of code into two statements:

```
notification = new Notification({title: "Message Received",body: "message body"})

notification.show()

notification.on('click', (event, arg)=>{
  console.log("clicked")
})
```

Comment: I did this and don't get errors, but it also doesn't register the click. That is... it never console logs anything. :\

Comment: I'm having the same problem (Electron 11.1.1)

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle the click event before calling the show method. The code below works on my end on Electron 10.1.1 (not sure how far back you can go before this stops working)

```
notification = new Notification({ title: "Test Title", body: "Test Body" });

notification.on('click', (event, arg) => {
  console.log("clicked");
});

notification.show();
```

Comment: Great find! The accepted answer is wrong and this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and it frayed a lot of nerves. This problem is Windows OS problem. The click handler worked in dev mode, but did not work after building in prod.
But I found the solution. Maybe it will be helpfull for you.
The problem is that missing between your appId, so notification and click on it don't have connection with your application.

How to resolve this isuue:
In your `forge.config.js` find your appBundleId or set it:

```
packagerConfig: {
    appBundleId: 'my.app.id',
    ...
}
```

And then in main process you should write:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
      app.setAppUserModelId('my.app.id');
    }
    createWindow();
    createNotification();
  });
```

After that, your notify click listner will be work not only in dev, but in prod!
I hope my solution was useful to you.